# android download blob always get different bytes from original

Tags: android

I have an android project that will download blob data from server and read the bytes, the blob data came from raw file that I have uploaded before. But when i download the blob data from the android application and read the bytes, it's return different byte size than in the server. The length is always 1340, can someone tell me what is wrong so I always get that length? is there any limit to download blob data in android? or if you have any example code that download the blob data, please share to me so I can analyst what's wrong with my code. This is the doInBackground code.

```
@Override
protected byte[] doInBackground(String... params) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
byte[] result = null;
String str="";
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(params[0]);// in this case, params[0] is URL
try {
    // set up post data
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    Iterator<String> it = mData.keySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        String key = it.next();
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair(key, mData.get(key)));
    }

    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair, "UTF-8"));
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
    StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
    if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
        result =EntityUtils.toByteArray(response.getEntity());
        str = new String(result, "UTF-8");

    }
}
catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (Exception e) {
}
return result;
}
```

Please help me, I have spend 2 days without progress here, Thank you very much....

Answer (score 0):

Check the [String API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5B%5D,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29)

`The length of the new String is a function of the charset, and hence may not be equal to the length of the byte array.`

Comment: As you can see, I don't make string as the return value, I set byte as the type of return value, but the length is always different so the raw file that I have downloaded always be a corrupt file. If you know or have sample code how to download blob data in android please share to me. Anyway, thanks for your reply.

Comment: Oh.. so, how are you measuring the size? Why do you need the string anyway?

Comment: Your code is fine. If the blob is very large in size, and if the server is slow, the download might get interrupted, in which case you will get an exception. So, add some logging and perhaps some handling.

Comment: my blob is just about 76 kb, is this very large to download with android? I don't think so. I measure it with .length function and I also write it to sdcard i another method, and the result between the file that has been written and the Toast in .length function are same. But once more, it's different with the original file. But if I download the blob with my php application, the file is working, not corrupt and has the ssame file size with the original. I have add some logging and exception but that's not help.There's no error there, what do you mean with handling?

Comment: Its not large. Post the relevant code in which you are trying to measure the length and I can help.